# How to write a shell script where to add days month and year to current date

Tags: shell, unix-timestamp

I am new to shell script.

I want to write a script where I add days month and years to current day.
for example it take current date and every time addd 3 to day 4 to months and 2 to years.
all the three things given as arguments.

I would really appreciate it.

Br

Comment: @shellter Thanls Buddy:) I'll try my best ! Bless

Answer (score 11):

Tip: fire up a terminal(in my case bash terminal)

the help is a good starting point

```
date --help
```

or man page

```
man date
```

A lot of information and examples.

Date manipulation in bash (copy paste the example run in your terminal):

add 10 days to the current date:

```
date -d "10 day" +"%Y %m %d"
```

or remove 10 days to the current date

```
date -d "-10 day" +"%Y %m %d"
```

add 2 months  to the current date:

```
date -d "2 month" +"%Y %m %d"
```

remove 2 months from the current date:

```
date -d "-2 month" +"%Y %m %d"
```

add 1 year to the current date

```
date -d "1 year" +"%Y %m %d"
```

remove 1 year to the current date

```
date -d "-1 year" +"%Y %m %d"
```

mixing add 1 year month and day

```
date -d "1 year 1 month 1 day" +"%Y %m %d"
```

in a script (in my case bash)

```
foobaa=`date -d "1 year 1 month 1 day" +"%Y %m %d"`
echo $foobaa
```

I hope it helps a little..

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent on Mac OSX is date -v "+60M" to add 60 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple command in short is** 
date -d "+3 days +4 Month +2 Years"

**Similarly, you can also subtract dates too.**
date -d "-3 days -4 Month -2 Years"